# Retrieve custom labels in salesforce dynamically without mentioning the name of the label in the code

Tags: custom, label

I am trying to retrieve the list of custom labels created into a list table format or in excel. All the solutions I have viewed so far is by mentioning the name of the label to retrieve the description. I want to be able to retrieve the list dynamically without mentioning the name of the label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Metadata API to pull down all the labels at once by using the wildcard character.

Here is an example package.xml for accomplishing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomLabels</name>
  </types>
<version>34.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, this worked! But is there a way we can schedule it somewhere to run every day or something? I want the latest custom labels to be retrieved in regular intervals.

Comment: No problem.  If you have a server available you could write a cron job to do the retrieve on a scheduled basis, but that is probably a separate question.

Comment: This solution works, but hoped that we could do this on a regular basis automatically! :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apex Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SObjects.htm?search_text=sobject%20types):

> Custom labels are not standard sObjects. You cannot create a new instance of a custom label. You can only access the value of a custom
>   label using `system.label.label_name`. For example:

```
String errorMsg = System.Label.generic_error;
```

It would seem there's no way around passing the value of the label_name through the system method in order to dynamically get the custom label.